# How to restore accidentally deleted a kube-proxy DaemonSet in a Kubernetes cluster?

Tags: kubernetes, kube-proxy

I accidentally deleted kube-proxy daemonset by using command: `kubectl delete -n kube-system daemonset kube-proxy` which should run kube-proxy pods in my cluster, what the best way to restore it?
[That's how it should look](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AChcS.png)

Comment: If you find my answer was helpful. please accept and upvote my answer for greater visibility of the community.

Answer (score 2):

Kubernetes allows you to [reinstall kube-proxy](https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/setup-tools/kubeadm/generated/kubeadm_init_phase_addon_kube-proxy/) by running the following command which install the kube-proxy addon components via the API server.

```
$ kubeadm init phase addon kube-proxy --kubeconfig ~/.kube/config --apiserver-advertise-address string
```

This will generate the output as

```
[addons] Applied essential addon: kube-proxy
```

The IP address the API Server will advertise it's listening on. If not set the default network interface will be used.

Hence  kube-proxy will be reinstalled in the cluster by creating a [DaemonSet](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/workloads/controllers/daemonset/) and launching the pods.

Comment: very cool, spent ages looking for something like this

Answer (score 0):

kube-proxy daemon got created at the time of cluster creation, so you need to write your own manifest for daemon-set unless you have a backup to restore it from there.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).